# Pig Load value from HBase as variable

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

In pig we can define variables and use it in multiple places.

```
%declare variable_name 'value'
```

In my example i have HBase table. I have only one row and one column. The value of that cell is the name of a dynamic table. So i want to read that value and need to use that value in other queries as well. I have written.

```
table_name = LOAD 'hbase://sample'
                USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('table_name:passive','-limit 1')
                AS (table_name:chararray);
```

How i can use this table_name value as char_array variable value and use it in multiple plcaes?

Comment: Where do you want to use it? In PIG script?

Answer (score 0):

In pig script we can't have scalar variables in left hand side. left hand side aliases can be only iterator of tuples. In order to get the arguments i have written a shell script to get arguments from HBase table and passed as argument to shell script. In shell script use pipeline to extract values.

```
argument=$(echo "hbase query to get value" | hbase shell | grep value | grep -o "value=.*" | cut -f2- -d'=')
```

Then pass it to pig script as argument.

```
pig  -param argument1=$argument -f sample.pig
```